# Удаление дубликатов SQL c join

Tags: sql

Собственно запутался в своем случае
Есть две таблицы в первой table1 id с множеством параметров

```
id | atribut 
1  | 100
2  | 200
3  | 200
4  | 200
5  | 100
```

есть вторая таблица table2 где к id присваиваются номера

```
totje_id | nomera
       1 | 11
       1 | 22
       2 | 11
       2 | 22
       2 | 33
       3 | 11
       4 | 22
       5 | 33
```

Собственно удалить мне нужно все дубликаты по полю atribut в первой таблицы, но если есть во второй таблице допустим номер 33, то именно его оставлять (но номер 33 не всегда есть), то есть в данном случае должно остаться

```
2 | 200
5 | 100
```

Обычно я использую delete... (select max(id)...), а тут не знаю как добавить проверку, ведь where не могу использовать?

Сделал запрос вроде бы то что мне надо, но как я теперь выберу все id без nomera = 33 в случае когда он есть?

```
SELECT atribut , table2.nomera, count(*) 
FROM table1
join table2
on table1.id = table2.totje_id
GROUP BY atribut, nomera

HAVING count(atribut)>1 AND nomera <> 33
```

То есть в случае когда в списке есть 33, мне надо ведь выбрать все без него и удалить, а когда нет 33 то выбрать все кроме одного. Сорян я нуб

Comment: Что значит когда нет 33 то выбрать все кроме одного. Кого одного?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT 
 atribut , 
 table2.nomera, 
 count(*)
FROM table1
join table2
 on table1.id = table2.totje_id
where nomera<>33
GROUP BY atribut, nomera
HAVING count(atribut)>1
```